# Partial View Does Not Recognize Another Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I am creating a partial view for the login which will be using the default model (AccountModel) and controller (AccountController) which were added when a new MVC 3 project is created.

However, the partial view (Login) does not recognize the controller (AccountController). I am getting "The resource cannot be found" error when I hit the "Register" link. Below is the snippet of the code.

Please advice.

Thanks

### _Layout.cshtml

```
 <div>
   <div id="SideBar">
        <div id="LoginHeader">
           Login
        </div>
        <div id = "Login">
            @Html.Partial("UserControls/UserLogin", new BalanzLab.Models.LogOnModel())
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

### UserLogin.cshtml

```
@model BalanzLab.Models.LogOnModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogOn", "AccountController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AccountController" }))
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Html.DisplayFor(Context.User.Identity);
    }
    else
    {
        <div >User Name
          @Html.TextBox(" ")
        </div>
        <div>Password
          @Html.Password(" ")
        </div>
        <div>
          @Html.ActionLink("Signup", "Register", "AccountController") 
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Let me in!" /></p>
     }
```

}

Comment: what is the file structure like?

Comment: The the partial view is at Views\Home\UserControls\UserLogin.cshtml. The account controller is at the project root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with where you have the UserLogin shared view and how you're referencing it.

First the how:

You're including the partial view from your _layout view. Therefore, it's in every page that uses that layout.

Now consider what you're doing here. When you click that Register link that's supposed to take you to the Account controller Register method, it's hitting the call to @Html.Partial:

```
@Html.Partial("UserControls/UserLogin", new BalanzLab.Models.LogOnModel())
```

and trying to include it in the current page. Since the UserLogin control is actually under a folder in the Home views directory, it's not in the standard search path of where the view engine will search. It will check within the Accounts directory of views (the current controller) and it will check the Shared views directory. Since it can't find the partial view in either location, you get your error. (which looks something like this)

```
The partial view 'UserControls/UserLogin' was not found or no view engine 
supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Account/UserControls/UserLogin.aspx
~/Views/Account/UserControls/UserLogin.ascx
~/Views/Shared/UserControls/UserLogin.aspx
~/Views/Shared/UserControls/UserLogin.ascx
~/Views/Account/UserControls/UserLogin.cshtml
~/Views/Account/UserControls/UserLogin.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/UserControls/UserLogin.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/UserControls/UserLogin.vbhtml
```

The cleanest solution is to move this partial view to the shared views directory. Since it's part of the _layout view, you almost have to do this to make this work as the partial will be included by every view that uses the layout.